# Ruby Net::Telnet waitfor() doesnt work

Tags: ruby, regex, telnet, waitforsingleobject

i have check out many different ways to fix this and it might be specific to the enviroment.
i'm creating a script in Ruby to telnet into a remote server, login, enter the shell type (its a prompt after logging in and has no "prompt" in front) and then entering a userid at the next prompt. currently it gets logged in via user and pass, but freezes at the term part.
i have tried to use regex, strings, sleep and then just puts("xterm" but nothing allows it to go past this prompt.
 here is a snippet of code that is getting hung up and the output to go along:

```
$telnet = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => 'hostname',
                       "Output_log" => 'output.txt',
                       "Dump_log" => 'Dump.txt',
                       "Binmode" => false,
                       "Timeout" => false,
                       "Prompt" => /.* $ $/) { |c| print c }
$telnet.login("user", "pass") { |c| print c }
$telnet.waitfor("TERM = (xterm) ")
$telnet.puts("xterm") { |c| print c }
$telnet.waitfor(Match => /Enter\s*$/) { |c| print c }
$telnet.puts("userid")
```

the output is as follows:

```
HP-UX ds107492 B.11.11 U 9000/800 (tm)

login: user
Password: 
Please wait...checking for disk quotas
. i

.[ci

.*s1^i

See /etc/copyright for copyright notices
You have mail.
'You have mail.'
TERM = (xterm)
```

Comment: You may want to look at the Ruby `ssh` gem. It works well, and also the source code is short and sweet if you want to read how it handles socket input/output including pauses and delays.

Comment: i was thinking about ssh, or net::ssh-telnet, but in our enviroment, we have to use telnet as a "security" function

Comment: as an update, i have tried net-ssh-telnet, and it gets hung up on the same area, same for perl Net::Telnet. i talked to the sec. guys at work and told me what i had to do to ensure "security" protocols. i am able to use ssh now :) still no fix though

Answer (score 1):

```
$s.waitfor("Match" => /TERM\s*/){ |c| print c }
$s.print("xterm\n"){ |c| print c }
```

seems to be the answer, it allowed me to go past the prompt. still not sure what the difference between this regex and all the others i tried are :/